# Filter array if element is present in another array based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object array like this:

```
var objectArray = [{id_5:"100"},
                   {id_1:"300"},
                   {id_2:"500"},
                   {id_4:"700"},
                   {id_3:"200"}];
```

And a normal array like this:

```
var normalArray = ["id_2","id_5","id_4"];
```

I want to subtract every element from the objectArray if there's a matching ID in the normalArray. I then want to order the newly created array by the object's value (lowest value being first).

So for the above example the result would be:

```
var newObjectArray = [{id_3:"200"},
                      {id_1:"300"}];
```

Is it possible to do this without jQuery?

I've seen similar questions like this one: [Removing object from one array if present in another array based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514523/removing-object-from-one-array-if-present-in-another-array-based-on-value) but I haven't been able to find an answer that works. Is it possible to do a compare and remove like this while still keeping the key:value pairs intact? Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Everything is possible in JS without jQuery, since jQuery is written in JS.

Comment: @Emily,it worked my solution for you ?

Answer (score 5):

You should use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, which accepts as parameter a `callback` function.

Also, you have to use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method in order to get the key of each `object` in `objectArray`.

To check if an `element` from `objectArray` doesn't appear in `objectArray`, you should use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method.

To achieve the `sorted` array, you have to use [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

```js
var objectArray = [{id_5:"100"},
                   {id_1:"300"},
                   {id_2:"500"},
                   {id_4:"700"},
                   {id_3:"200"}];

var normalArray = ["id_2","id_5","id_4"];
var newArray=objectArray.filter(function(item){
    return normalArray.indexOf(Object.keys(item)[0]) == -1;
}).sort(function(a,b){
    return a[Object.keys(a)[0]] - b[Object.keys(b)[0]];
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first use `filter()` to remove object with key from other array and then sort to sort result array by objects value.

```js
var objectArray = [{id_5:"100"},{id_1:"300"},{id_2:"500"},{id_4:"700"},{id_3:"200"}];
var normalArray = ["id_2","id_5","id_4"];

var newArray = objectArray
  .filter(e => !normalArray.includes(Object.keys(e)[0]))
  .sort((a, b) => a[Object.keys(a)[0]] - b[Object.keys(b)[0]])
  
console.log(newArray)
```